# How to style control hosting OAuth login dialog of WinRT WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync?

Tags: xaml, oauth, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm using OAuth to authenticate a user in my WinRT application (C#/XAML). All works fine, except for the login dialog being shown in a control for which I can't seem to provide any styling options.

Here's my (pseudo) code:

```
var requestUri = new Uri("my oauth request uri"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var callbackUri = new Uri("my oauth redirect uri", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var authenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, requestUri, callbackUri);
```

The call to AuthenticateAsync makes sure the login form is shown, but it appears centered in a control, showing both horizontal and vertical scrollbars, which doesn't look nice. I'd like to **style this hosting container control of this Web form**.

Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Is there not a control template available?

Comment: Seems the third party API provider should do the styling of the page, as there's no possibility to do it client side in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you connecting to third party service or you own the server side of oAuth? oAuth provider can follow guidelines to make dialog prettier. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj856911

Comment: I'm connecting to a third party service (StackExchange API)

Comment: ok. in that case StackExchange have to make necessary modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change style of `AuthenticationDialog`. Same is true for other built-in dialog boxes like `CredentialPicker` etc.